# Как сделать чтоб PDF файл создавался обычным бланком черно белым?

Tags: javascript, pdf

Вот такой вид pdf имеет при сохранении у меня на сайте

```
https://cloud.mail.ru/public/ECDp/NFmdsx735
```

А мне надо вот так `https://cloud.mail.ru/public/C7B1/SyuRFT8Vn`
Заранее спасибо

```js
$(function() {
  var specialElementHandlers = {
    '#editor': function(element, renderer) {
      return true;
    }
  };
  $('#cmd').click(function() {
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.fromHTML($('#myModal').html(), 15, 15, {
      'width': 170,
      'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
    });
    doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
  });
});

function genPDF() {
  html2canvas($("#content"), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      var img = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      console.log(img);
      var doc = new jsPDF();
      doc.addImage(img, 'JPEG', 20, 20);
      doc.save('test.pdf');
    }
  });
}


function genPDF() {
  exportOne();
  gen2canvas();
};

function exportOne() {
  var pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'px', [1123, 794]),
    source = $('#content');

  pdf.addHTML(
    source, 0, 0, {
      pagesplit: true
    },
    function(dispose) {
      pdf.save('test.pdf');
    }
  );
}

function gen2canvas() {
  html2canvas($('#content'), {
    onrendered: function(canvas) {
      document.body.appendChild(canvas);
    },
    width: 1123
  });
};
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/1.12.0/semantic.min.css">


<button onclick="genPDF()" class="btn btn-danger">generate PDF</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<div id="content">
  <table id="content" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
        <td>System Architect</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2011/04/25</td>
        <td>$320,800</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Garrett Winters</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>63</td>
        <td>2011/07/25</td>
        <td>$170,750</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Ashton Cox</td>
        <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>66</td>
        <td>2009/01/12</td>
        <td>$86,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
        <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>2012/03/29</td>
        <td>$433,060</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Airi Satou</td>
        <td>Accountant</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>33</td>
        <td>2008/11/28</td>
        <td>$162,700</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2012/12/02</td>
        <td>$372,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>59</td>
        <td>2012/08/06</td>
        <td>$137,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>55</td>
        <td>2010/10/14</td>
        <td>$327,900</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
        <td>Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>39</td>
        <td>2009/09/15</td>
        <td>$205,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Sonya Frost</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>2008/12/13</td>
        <td>$103,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jena Gaines</td>
        <td>Office Manager</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>2008/12/19</td>
        <td>$90,560</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Quinn Flynn</td>
        <td>Support Lead</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>2013/03/03</td>
        <td>$342,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Charde Marshall</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>36</td>
        <td>2008/10/16</td>
        <td>$470,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Haley Kennedy</td>
        <td>Senior Marketing Designer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>43</td>
        <td>2012/12/18</td>
        <td>$313,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Tatyana Fitzpatrick</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>2010/03/17</td>
        <td>$385,750</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Michael Silva</td>
        <td>Marketing Designer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>66</td>
        <td>2012/11/27</td>
        <td>$198,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Paul Byrd</td>
        <td>Chief Financial Officer (CFO)</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>64</td>
        <td>2010/06/09</td>
        <td>$725,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Gloria Little</td>
        <td>Systems Administrator</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>59</td>
        <td>2009/04/10</td>
        <td>$237,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bradley Greer</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>41</td>
        <td>2012/10/13</td>
        <td>$132,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Dai Rios</td>
        <td>Personnel Lead</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>35</td>
        <td>2012/09/26</td>
        <td>$217,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jenette Caldwell</td>
        <td>Development Lead</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>2011/09/03</td>
        <td>$345,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Yuri Berry</td>
        <td>Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>40</td>
        <td>2009/06/25</td>
        <td>$675,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Caesar Vance</td>
        <td>Pre-Sales Support</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>2011/12/12</td>
        <td>$106,450</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Doris Wilder</td>
        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
        <td>Sidney</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>2010/09/20</td>
        <td>$85,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Angelica Ramos</td>
        <td>Chief Executive Officer (CEO)</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>47</td>
        <td>2009/10/09</td>
        <td>$1,200,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Gavin Joyce</td>
        <td>Developer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>42</td>
        <td>2010/12/22</td>
        <td>$92,575</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jennifer Chang</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>Singapore</td>
        <td>28</td>
        <td>2010/11/14</td>
        <td>$357,650</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Brenden Wagner</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>28</td>
        <td>2011/06/07</td>
        <td>$206,850</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Fiona Green</td>
        <td>Chief Operating Officer (COO)</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>48</td>
        <td>2010/03/11</td>
        <td>$850,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Shou Itou</td>
        <td>Regional Marketing</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>2011/08/14</td>
        <td>$163,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Michelle House</td>
        <td>Integration Specialist</td>
        <td>Sidney</td>
        <td>37</td>
        <td>2011/06/02</td>
        <td>$95,400</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Suki Burks</td>
        <td>Developer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>53</td>
        <td>2009/10/22</td>
        <td>$114,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Prescott Bartlett</td>
        <td>Technical Author</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>27</td>
        <td>2011/05/07</td>
        <td>$145,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Gavin Cortez</td>
        <td>Team Leader</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>2008/10/26</td>
        <td>$235,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Martena Mccray</td>
        <td>Post-Sales support</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>46</td>
        <td>2011/03/09</td>
        <td>$324,050</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Unity Butler</td>
        <td>Marketing Designer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>47</td>
        <td>2009/12/09</td>
        <td>$85,675</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Howard Hatfield</td>
        <td>Office Manager</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>51</td>
        <td>2008/12/16</td>
        <td>$164,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hope Fuentes</td>
        <td>Secretary</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>41</td>
        <td>2010/02/12</td>
        <td>$109,850</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Vivian Harrell</td>
        <td>Financial Controller</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>62</td>
        <td>2009/02/14</td>
        <td>$452,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Timothy Mooney</td>
        <td>Office Manager</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>37</td>
        <td>2008/12/11</td>
        <td>$136,200</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jackson Bradshaw</td>
        <td>Director</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>65</td>
        <td>2008/09/26</td>
        <td>$645,750</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Olivia Liang</td>
        <td>Support Engineer</td>
        <td>Singapore</td>
        <td>64</td>
        <td>2011/02/03</td>
        <td>$234,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Bruno Nash</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>38</td>
        <td>2011/05/03</td>
        <td>$163,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Sakura Yamamoto</td>
        <td>Support Engineer</td>
        <td>Tokyo</td>
        <td>37</td>
        <td>2009/08/19</td>
        <td>$139,575</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Thor Walton</td>
        <td>Developer</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>61</td>
        <td>2013/08/11</td>
        <td>$98,540</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Finn Camacho</td>
        <td>Support Engineer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>47</td>
        <td>2009/07/07</td>
        <td>$87,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Serge Baldwin</td>
        <td>Data Coordinator</td>
        <td>Singapore</td>
        <td>64</td>
        <td>2012/04/09</td>
        <td>$138,575</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Zenaida Frank</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>63</td>
        <td>2010/01/04</td>
        <td>$125,250</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Zorita Serrano</td>
        <td>Software Engineer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>56</td>
        <td>2012/06/01</td>
        <td>$115,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jennifer Acosta</td>
        <td>Junior Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>43</td>
        <td>2013/02/01</td>
        <td>$75,650</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Cara Stevens</td>
        <td>Sales Assistant</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>46</td>
        <td>2011/12/06</td>
        <td>$145,600</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Hermione Butler</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>47</td>
        <td>2011/03/21</td>
        <td>$356,250</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Lael Greer</td>
        <td>Systems Administrator</td>
        <td>London</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>2009/02/27</td>
        <td>$103,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Jonas Alexander</td>
        <td>Developer</td>
        <td>San Francisco</td>
        <td>30</td>
        <td>2010/07/14</td>
        <td>$86,500</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Shad Decker</td>
        <td>Regional Director</td>
        <td>Edinburgh</td>
        <td>51</td>
        <td>2008/11/13</td>
        <td>$183,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Michael Bruce</td>
        <td>Javascript Developer</td>
        <td>Singapore</td>
        <td>29</td>
        <td>2011/06/27</td>
        <td>$183,000</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Donna Snider</td>
        <td>Customer Support</td>
        <td>New York</td>
        <td>27</td>
        <td>2011/01/25</td>
        <td>$112,000</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.3.0/jspdf.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/0.5.0-alpha2/dist/html2canvas.min.js"></script>

!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="content">
          <h3>Hello, this is a H3 tag</h3>
          <a class="upload">Upload to Imgur</a>
          <h2>this is <b>bold</b> <span style="color:red">red</span></h2>
          <p>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я изучил документацию [jsPDF](http://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/jsPDF.html) и осмелюсь предположить, что во время использования метода `fromHTML` вы не сможете задать стили, полученного HTML. Поясню конкретнее, если попробовать написать код следующим образом (получение PDF):

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.setTextColor(0, 255, 0);
doc.text(20, 20, 'It is a green color!');
doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
```

То в результате мы получим надпись зеленого цвета, в сгенерированном PDF файле. Касаемо вашего кода, предоставленного в вопросе:

```
var doc = new jsPDF();
doc.fromHTML($('#myModal').html(), 15, 15, {
  'width': 170,
  'elementHandlers': specialElementHandlers
});
doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
```

то тут, что было получено из HTML, то и будет вставлено в сгенерированный PDF файл. И никакими вспомогательными методами из jsPDF не изменить стилей. К примеру вот тут об этом говорится: [jsPDF can't get any styling to work](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20518296/5275890). В этом же ответе, автор пишет, что можно делать вот так:

```
doc.setFontSize(22);
doc.setTextColor(255, 0, 0);
doc.text(20, 20, 'This is a title');

doc.setFontSize(16);
doc.setTextColor(0, 255, 0);
doc.text(20, 30, 'This is some normal sized text underneath.');
```

Но это не ваш случай. Поэтому, вам нужно подготовить контент, который в последствии будет вставлен в PDF файл. Иными словами вот этот блок:

```
$('#myModal').html()
```

вам нужно передать в написанный вами метод (которого пока не существует), который будет реплэйсить цвета и возвращать вам отредактированный HTML, который вы в последствии вставите в PDF файл.

Полезная ссылка по jsPDF: [EXPORT HTML WEB PAGE TO PDF USING JSPDF](https://micropyramid.com/blog/export-html-web-page-to-pdf-using-jspdf/)

Comment: Мне вообще без стилей надо, Ч/Б содержимое и все.

Comment: спасибо вам за ответ, но ведь у других как то получается код подпрпавлять чтоб страница принимала не вид html, а вид DOC документа в pdf формате. С уважением

Comment: @Arcadiy так о том и речь, что в PDF прилетит все, что есть в HTML. Только парсинг входящего HTML с удалением всех стилей заданого цвета, либо заменой на черный (серый). Средствами jsPDF не получится.

Comment: Денис если это не возможно, хотя-бы подскажите пожалуйста как сделать, что-бы лист на выходе был не альбомный, а книжный и как определенный столбец не включить на вывод pdf? заранее спасибо Вам, с уважением.

Comment: огромное спасибо, с уважением

Comment: @Arcadiy `new jsPDF('landscape');` - альбомная ориентация страницы, `new jsPDF('portrait');` - портретная. Значение ориентации по умолчанию - `portrait`. Касаемо столбцов - снова нужно редактировать HTML, ведь в PDF попадет все, что есть в HTML.

Comment: При портрете шрифт в таблице вытянутый https://cloud.mail.ru/public/ApcB/L79DEjyxX

Comment: @Arcadiy, думаю это по причине  `width="100%"` у таблицы. Поэтому заполняется во всю ширину. Попробуйте поменять значения ширины у контента, который вы вставляете в PDF.

Comment: Спасибо большой